# Start RDP as Shell

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop, windows-explorer

I have a WinXP installation that is used to only connect to another PC with RDP.

A dummy user account gets logged in automatically, then the user must click a link to start the RDP connection with predefined parameters.

Is there a way to run the RDP client without Windows Explorer being accessible?

Comment: It sounds almost as if you'd rather have an ssh connection to the other PC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit the Registry to replace the default shell program (Explorer.exe) with the `MSTSC.exe` application and include any valid parameters you wish to use.

In the Registry, navigate to **[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon]** and change the value named **Shell** to:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\MSTSC.exe /V:YourServerName
```

You can replace the `/V` parameter with the specific ones you want.

One caveat of this solution is that when your user exits the Remote Desktop application they'll be presented with a blank screen and must press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>
 and choose **Logoff** to get back to the local machine's logon prompt.  Because of this you may consider pointing the Shell registry value to a batch script that runs the `Logoff.exe` program after `MSTSC.EXE` ends such as the solution found [here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Microsoft_Operating_Systems/Windows/A_10032-MSTSC-as-a-Shell.html).

An even more flexible solution can be found [here](http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/235665-turn-old-pcs-into-rdp-winterms?page=1#entry-2605638).  It involves pointing the Shell registry value to a simple HTA application that lets the user run MSTSC repeatedly or reboot the workstation.  A working HTA application is available at the link.