# Is it possible to launch Chrome in kiosk mode in Windows 10 without showing the desktop?

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome, kiosk

I cannot find a reliable solution to start chrome (in kiosk mode) in Windows 10 at system startup, without showing the desktop environment.

More precisely, i CAN start Chrome in kiosk mode, but it takes a lot of time on our target devices (Industrial tablets) so whenever the device get rebooted, end users can see the desktop environment for 10-11 seconds.

Is it worth to try playing with chrome flags? i tried to disable some unused features but startup time doesn't change that much.

Windows Kiosk mode seems to work only with other browsers (IE) and the app i need to launch requires chrome, so I don't have many choices...

I cannot run chrome with the Windows Kiosk Mode because chrome is not compatible (not UWP), so I am just auto logging in the user, starting chrome at startup with the following flags:

"C:\path\to\chrome.exe" --kiosk --incognito --disable-pinch "file:\\C:\path\to\app.html"

Comment: The technique in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/749985/213131) might be what you're looking for.

Comment: How are you running Chrome while in Kiosk mode, the Windows 10 Kiosk mode, only supports UWP applications?  Are you using a third-party Kiosk solution?  Please edit your question and provide as much detail as possible.

Comment: Not using any third party kiosk.... just auto login, start chrome at startup and run it with --kiosk --incognito and --disable-pinch flags. I updated the answer for future reference.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator I'm trying that right now and it seems to work perfectly! I just have to work on some startup details. My search keywords were off apparently :(

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into your question. [su] is a question and answer site and answers should be separate from questions. You can [answer your own question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) instead.

Comment: I didn't answer my question for two reasons: 1. there already was an answer as pointed by TwistyImpersonator. 2. The solution was provided by TwistyImpersonator so he might want to write the solution as an answer :)